# How could I make the icon stay always by right side of selection input?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How could I make the icon stay always by right side of selection input? I would like to make the selection expand just until the icon by it's side touch the container edge.

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Justificativa</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Don't care about it. It's making a select tag that have width 100% -->
    <%= select_tag "loja[rf_justificativa]",
                                        options_for_select(rf_justificativas_lojas,
                                                                             selected: @loja.rf_justificativa),
                                        class: "campo_ai"
                                    %>
      <%= text_field_tag "loja[rf_justificativa]",
                                        @loja.rf_justificativa,
                                        class: "campo_ai hidden"
                                    %>
        <!-- Here is the icon that I want to show by side of the select -->
    <a class="ativa_inativa" href="#" title="Editar">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm also using Selectize.js to my select fields. To make it expand I use this CSS.

```
.col-md-12 .selectize-control {
  width: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvc7dfa7/

Comment: add a CSS rule to your icon. float: right;

Comment: @NickM didn't worked. :(

Comment: I did solve it by adding the icon by side of the label instead of the input ( select )

Answer (score 2):

an easy way is to use the columns you have already but have

```
<div class="col-md-11"> <select></div>
<div class="col-md-1"> <icon> </div>
```

If it has to be right beside it and inside the column you can do it with CSS. Giving them both the property:

```
display:inline-block;
```

It may even work just giving the icon a:

```
float:right;
```

I hope this helps.

I have fixed it for you in your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pvc7dfa7/1/

You need to wrap the select/ icon in DIVs then apply the styles I mentioned.

Pete

Comment: I did try to set both to `display:inline-block;` and the link a `float:right;` without success.

Comment: I've already try before make the 11 and 1 columns, but it get so far from each other. And it jumps line when reducing windows size.

Comment: The drop down icon collapsed over the text and the field is not expanding all de width that is available.

Comment: Play with the sizing, I'm not gonna do the whole thing for you. Give the container divs some width and adjust until you're happy.
    .left{
        width: 90%;
    }

    .right{
        width:1%;
    }

Comment: Thanks you for your help. Sorry if I looked lazy. I did solve my problem changing the way that I'll present this form feature by adding it into the label side instead of the field.

Comment: Cool, glad to help out :) the style is all up to you but this problem has caught me out lots of times so worth sharing. Another good way is to use <ul> and <li> to contain your elements but hide the style with CSS. Happy coding!